# Error Unexpected token { in JSON at position 64

Tags: json, nestjs

```json
    {
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src"
}
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["mail/templates/**/*"], //   or "**/*.hbs" all files ending with .hbs
    "watchAssets": true //  copy assets in watch mode
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

if it two different objects then it should come as below.

```
[{
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src"
},
{
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "assets": [
            "mail/templates/**/*"
        ], //   or "**/*.hbs" all files ending with .hbs
        "watchAssets": true //  copy assets in watch mode
    }
}]
```